# ClassCastException on MergeSort implementation

Tags: java, mergesort

I was implementing the MergeSort algorithm but I am always getting a `ClassCastException` while converting it from `Object`.
For comparing two values of `K`, I used the `intValue` method. Is there any other way to compare them?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MergeSort {
    private static <K extends Number> K[] sort(K[] s) {
        int n = s.length;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return null;
        int mid = n / 2;
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            K[] s1 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2];
            K[] s2 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                s1[i] = s[i];
                s2[i] = s[i + n / 2];
            }
            return merge(sort(s1), sort(s2));
        } else {
            K[] s1 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2];
            K[] s2 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2 + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                s1[i] = s[i];
                s2[i] = s[i + n / 2];
            }
            s2[n / 2] = s[n - 1];
            return merge(sort(s1), sort(s2));
        }
    }

    private static <K extends Number> K[] merge(K[] s1,K[] s2){
        int ll, rl;
        ll = s1.length;
        rl = s2.length;
        K[] merge = (K[]) new Object[ll+rl];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i + j < ll + rl) {
            if (j == rl || (i < ll && (s1[i].intValue() < s2[j].intValue())))
                merge[i + j] = s1[i++];
            else
                merge[i + j] = s1[j++];
        }
        return merge;
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of objects is not an array of numbers. So `(K[]) new Object[n / 2];` doesn't make sense. In general, generics and arrays don't go well together. Use Lists. Or use arrays of objects, and cast their elements to K. Not the arrays themselves.

Comment: And you can use [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and/or [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in order to be even more general. If you insist on using arrays, you may want to take a look at [`ArrayList`'s implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java). Some remarks on your code: more meaningful variable names could be helpful, as well as some more blanks around the binary operators (especially w.r.t. the `merge(...)` method).

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat 
How can I make it minimal, I need to show whole code in order to present , how it is working

Comment: For example you should include the complete stack trace and show us the line given in the stack trace!

Comment: @GhostCat here StackTrace was just an exception is thrown and I presented the code to show how I am Achieving it because I am using Generic, so I also need to show where I am declaring the Array. Everytime it is not good option to use less code.

Comment: @Turing85 , I am not familiar with the Comparator
Otherwise I saw following code but here I dont know what will be the comp and how to use it 
    `private static <K> K[] mergeSort(K[] s, Comparator<K> comp)`

Comment: Sorry, it is simply not possible to answer this question. Either show us the code that throws this exception, or show us the code that uses intValur(). Then: read about using generics and arrays. You don't need to use generics here - you could simply write a sort () method that works for arrays of Number.

Comment: @GhostCat
            `K[] s1 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2];`
            `K[] s2 = (K[]) new Object[n / 2 + 1];`
this will throw Exception

Comment: Don't put more information into comments - enhance your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the exception:

You are creating arrays of *Object* in your sort method which you then cast to *K*.

But casting an array like this doesn't magically turn objects into K instances. Your whole idea how to use generics here doesn't make sense. Try implementing your sort for arrays of Number first.

And: normally you would create these "temp" arrays only in the merge step. Also having temp arrays for the first partitioning of data looks suspiciously like waste of memory.